# genstrings: How to update existing file with only new records without changing the translated ones?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, localization

I am building an app with multiple translations.

When I am using `genstrings` to generate the `.strings` files for languages, the existing files would be totally overridden to a state without any translation.

Every time, I need to recover the translated entries using `git` history one by one, which is not very productive.

Any ideas to add new translations only without modify the existing ones?